# No Network/Internet conneection Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: network-manager, 21.10

Yesterday I did an update (some PAM files update) of my system post logging off and login/restart I cannot connect to WIFI or internet. I don't have ethernet port on my laptop to cannot check it. My system is dualboot win11/ubuntu 21.1 with kde plasma desktop.

The output from syslog is this.

```
NetworkManager[594]: <error> [1641487978.9687] bus-manager: fatal failure to acquire D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Connection ":1.10" is not allowed to own the service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" due to security policies in the configuration file
Jan  6 22:22:58 ubuntu2004 thermald[619]: 22 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:8e:a (6:142:10)
Jan  6 22:22:58 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan  6 22:22:58 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan  6 22:22:58 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
Jan  6 22:22:58 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online.
Jan  6 22:22:58 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Job NetworkManager-wait-online.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan  6 22:22:59 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: kerneloops.service: Found left-over process 735 (kerneloops) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jan  6 22:22:59 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jan  6 22:22:59 ubuntu2004 NetworkManager[804]: <error> [1641487979.1058] bus-manager: fatal failure to acquire D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Connection ":1.18" is not allowed to own the service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" due to security policies in the configuration file
Jan  6 22:22:59 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan  6 22:22:59 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan  6 22:22:59 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
```

I am clueless how to resolve this issue. I tried restarting the NetworkManager but it did not help.

Looking for advice.

Update:

After installing `network-manager_1.32.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` package I am able to connect to internet through USB tethering. The Network icon appears in taskbar but no WIFI network are shown and hence cannot connect to WIFI.